# How to avoid repeat evaluation of EL

Tags: java, seam, richfaces

I'm developing a web interface with seam/richfaces.

Alot of the components has something akin to

```
<h:panelGrid rendered="#{complexbean.heavyoperation()}">
    ...
</h:panelGrid>
<h:panelGrid rendered="#{!complexbean.heavyoperation()}">
    ...
</h:panelGrid>
```

In this case the #{!complexbean.heavyoperation()} gets evaluated twice.

My question is, is there anything similar to if-else statements I can use in the page to avoid these multiple evaluation of the same EL (and I would like to avoid any uses of JSP stuff, i.e. %<% if ... %>% )?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see you are using `Seam`. Can't you just use a `@Factory` in one of your backing beans? In the same scope it will be evaluated only ONCE. This is its purpose.

```
@Factory("operation")
public bool heavyComputation() {
    return true;
}
```

And then your view:

```
<h:panelGrid rendered="#{!operation}">
    ...
</h:panelGrid>
<h:panelGrid rendered="#{!operation}">
    ...
</h:panelGrid>
```

I think this is much clearer. Hope that helps:)

Answer (score 0):

If you have nothing against jstl, you can use c:choose/c:when/c:otherwise construction.

Comment: Avoid using JSTL at all cost when using Facelets. You need to know what you are doing if you use JSTL tags, because of the way Facelets work.

Comment: You need to know what you are doing all the time, do not you?

Comment: No, not if you stay away from JSTL. Specifially the c:forEach tag and how it is rendered compared to Facelets, which is compile time versus runtime.